# AlarmManager start Alarm Instantly

Tags: android, android-layout, alarmmanager, android-alarms

I have created a form where user specify date and time and adds alarm. I take these date and time and creates Alarm using `AlarmManager`.

The problem is that as soon as I click on `CreateRemainder` button, Alarm is fired

I am using following method to pass date, time values to  `AlarmManager` class.

```
int year= Integer.parseInt(splitDate[0]);
int month= Integer.parseInt(splitDate[1]);
int day= Integer.parseInt(splitDate[2]);

int hour= Integer.parseInt(splitTime[0]);
int minute= Integer.parseInt(splitTime[1]);
int second= 0;


Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault(), Locale.getDefault());
cal.set(Calendar.DATE,day);  //1-31
cal.set(Calendar.MONTH,month-1);  //first month is 0!!! January is zero!!!
cal.set(Calendar.YEAR,year);//year...

cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);  //HOUR
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);       //MIN
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, second);

AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

I debug this and its getting the correct values, but it starts alarm immediately.
If i change the `AlarmManager` time to hard codded 10 seconds time, it starts remainder after 10 seconds.

```
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,  System.currentTimeMillis() + (10 * 1000), pendingIntent);
```

But if i add 10 Seconds to the Calender, it still start displaying  alarm instantly after setting it.

```
 alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis()+10000, pendingIntent);
```

Comment: Instead of `System time` get `alarm manger` time.

Comment: @Kirmani88.. I saw that you accepted my answer... Could you please comment my answer and tell us how do you fixed? For future reference...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, if the alarm is being fired as soon as you set it, it means that scheduled time is behind current time... So, AlarmManager fires it imediatelly

I suggest to add debug messages to debug. Something like:

```
Log.d("DEBUG", "Time from device: " +  Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() + " Time passed to alarm: " + cal.getTimeInMillis());
```

Then, you can check [Current Millis](https://currentmillis.com/) website and check if both times are correct.. **Check if cal is really a future date**

Also, if you want to add a time to calendar, use as follows `Calendar.add()` method:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 10);

AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

Comment: The main problem was in the month, I was subtracting -1 from the Month, that's why it starts the Alarm just after adding it, because it was a month  old.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC, cal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
    } else {
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, cal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
    }
```

If your alarm is getting called instantly than my guess is your `cal`'s date is before today.

Comment: Thanks, as i read somewhere that `firstMonth` is 0, so i subtract -1 from whatever the month i get, Is it fine or i need to put the same month in the calendar.

Comment: Maybe you're not getting your dates right from `splitDate`, but your alarm's code looks just fine